# Concat multiple rows in SSIS in one column

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have two tables:

Table 1 (Name, (...), ProductID)

Table 2 (Customer Name, ProductID)

Sample Table 1

`Test1 | 1`

Sample Table 2:

`Customer1 | 1`

`Customer2 | 1`

The table schema is fixed and I cannot change it and I cannot create additional views, etc.
With SQL Server Integration Services I have to create a new table. Within this new table I need to have one column with the customers like `Customer1; Customer2` for `Test1`.

I know that I could do it with COALESCE, but I have no idea how to do that within SSIS. Which transformation should I use, and how?

**Update**
Here is the sample for COALESCE:

```
DECLARE @names VARCHAR(150) 

SELECT @names = COALESCE(@names + '; ', '') + [CustomerName]
  FROM Table2

SELECT @names
```

How to insert this snippet into one new `SELECT * FROM Table1`?

Comment: You say that the table schema is fixed, but, in the next sentence, you say you have to create a new table. Do you mean you can create a new table in a different database? How would you produce your results with COALESCE? What results are you looking for?

Comment: So, the desire is to create a delimited list of values (customer name) based for each ProductID? Is the source for this data SQL Server or a different RDBMS? If it's SQL Server, what version (2005/2008/2012)?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Sorry for not being specific enough. Yes the source database is fixed, and the new table will be created in a different database. Both are SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Does this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79103/3) reflect the intention of your source and destination?

Comment: Yes, that should be the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution:

```
SELECT [All_My_Other_Fields], STUFF(
             (SELECT '; ' + [CustomerName] 
              FROM Table2
              WHERE Table2.ProductID=Table1.ProductID
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '') AS Customers
FROM Table1
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Take your OLEDB source and use a SQL query for that source.

```
SELECT T1.Name, T2.Customer  
FROM [TABLE 1] AS T1
    INNER JOIN [Table 2] as T2
        ON T1.ProductID = T2.ProductID
```

Then use a data flow to move that to your OLEDB destination. No need to get fancy with SSIS on this if you can easily make the database engine handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that results in multiple rows. I want instead one resulting row with a column containing the data from table 2 (comma separated).

Answer (score 1):

Your best, and most performant, solution would be to use a SQL Query as your Source, instead of the raw tables.   Then you can do the COALESCE (or Concatenation) in the SQL query and it will be passed through the SSIS data pipe.

Comment: Ouch... that's it! Sometimes its too simple... ;-)

Comment: Could you improve your answer by explaining how `coalesce` is going to solve the problem? `Concat` is not an option since they are on SQL Server 2012

Comment: I don't know how Coalesce would solve the problem, but since the original poster mentioned it in the question, I mentioned it in my answer.  As for concat, are you saying that in SQL 2012 you can't do SELECT Column1 + ' ' + Column2?   I find that hard to believe, but I don't have 2012 yet.

Comment: You can certainly add columns on the same row into a single column. However, I believe the problem is that they need to condense a column on multiple *rows* into a single column on a single row.

Comment: In that case could it be done with FOR XML? That's how I would do it in 2005.   ...and wait, the OP's comment above says he is using 2008.

Comment: I have no idea, how FOR XML could solve it. See my updated question how I can do it with COALESCE but not in one SELECT with two tables as a source.